# JavaScript AWS SDK for S3, Rapid "Bad Request" Errors

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-sdk

I'm using the AWS.S3.upload method, with the following arguments:

---

```
var params = {
   Bucket: bucket,
   Key: fileKey,
   Body: file.slice(0, file.size+1)
};

var options = {
   partSize: megabytes * 1024 * 1024,
   queueSize: concurrentChunks
};
```

---

Note: I tried with queueSize ranging from 1 to 8 and megabytes per chunk ranging from 5 to 10, same issue. I am using the following sdk: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.250.1.min.js

So first of all, I want to make it clear that the upload is successful with this method, even for a 3GB file. However, every few seconds it throws the following error several times in a row, and drops the upload progress by 3-6% (seen from the httpUploadProgress event on the upload manager object):

---

```
PUT https://{bucket}.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/
{Identifier}/de2f2734512e9f4faf7b9ee333847697?
partNumber={partNum}&uploadId={uploadId} 400 (Bad Request)
```

---

So while the upload makes positive progress because it uploads 8-15% before the bad request spam, it is much slower than it could be if this wasn't happening. (Note: the physical reason it drops is because partial chunk upload progress is reported and on failure the entire chunk must re-upload.) It's also kind of alarming to see hundreds and hundreds of PUT errors in the console during an upload.

Looking at the response headers on any of the problem requests in the browser dev tools, I see the following: "X-Cache: Error from cloudfront." From analyzing the network traffic I have found that 5-8 requests will go through successfully, followed by 1-5 failed requests. Sometimes it will interleave with 1 successful, 1 failed, 1 successful... and so on.

Any ideas about what is going on, if it's my fault or cloudfront's issue like the response header says, and where to go from here?

Thanks! (Note: I posted this to the Amazon AWS forum first, but there is seemingly almost no traffic to that forum.)

Comment: Note that the word "from" `X-Cache: Error from CloudFront` does not necessarily mean *caused by* or *inside of* CloudFront -- often, it only means *in a request handled by* CloudFront. CloudFront is where the heavy lifting of S3 Transfer Acceleration is done, and if S3 throws an error, even just a 404 or 403, that same header will be present.  If the responses also have `x-amz-request-id` and `x-amz-id-2` headers, and `Server: AmazonS3`, then the request definitely did make it all the way through to S3.  Do you see those?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael. Yes the `x-amz-request-id` and `x-amz-id-2` response headers are both present, as well as `Server: AmazonS3`. Thank you for the clarification on what the error from Cloudfront means. However, I suppose I'm just confused why the upload progress drops several percent each time one of these errors occur, if it's making it all the way to S3?

Comment: Multipart uploads operate in chunks of 5 MB minimum.  If a chunk fails, the entire chunk has to be re-sent.  If the progress is counting progress of partial chunks,  and they fail midway through, that could explain negative progress, but it would be good if we can find out why they are failing at all.  Unfortunately, `Bad Request` has several causes, and we need the response bodies to determine which it is.

Comment: Or... enabling [CloudTrail Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html) of object level actions might get us there, because the error message *appears* to be [captured](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference-record-contents.html).  If you have a support contract, the `x-amz-request-id` and `x-amz-id-2` along with `x-amz-cf-id` (probably not needed, depending on the nature of the error) can be used by the engineers to identify a specific request the internal logs of the service.

Comment: The majority of my experience with S3 has been working with the underlying services directly, without an official SDK (I wrote my own, not in JS), and the SDKs have a tendency toward overly-"helpful" behavior that swallows exceptions. But the JS SDK may provide a way to add handlers that let you capture those response bodies -- I just don't know.  The error is troubling, because both the service and the SDK should be behaving deterministically -- `400 Bad Request`, in the purest sense, means the client has created a request that is invalid to the extent that repeating it can never succeed.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the info! Yes, I know progress was dropping because entire chunks needed to be sent on fail.  My question above was inspired by your comment that they should be making it all the way to S3 (implying the error was superficial?), which I think was just my own confusion on your words. I would be curious to have Amazon look at an example `x-amz-request-id` and `x-amz-id-2`, because I'm not building these chunks myself (I was at one point) because I discovered their uploadManager which does all the chunking for you. Can't see how their own manager would generate invalid.

Comment: Yes, I intended to indicate that the *request* is making it "all the way to S3" in the sense that CloudFront isn't failing to deliver the request... not that the *content* was making it all the way.  The errors are real, not superficial, and I suspect you're right to be concerned... it's a question of why.  Posting to the official S3 forum and providing an example response with the three headers I mentioned *might* get you a response from an engineer who sends you a PM.  Those header values are either opaque or encrypted, so not considered sensitive.. but I wouldn't mention the bucket name.

Comment: Ah, I understand! I will gather this data and make a post there. Thank you for your guidance!